# Rest api call using post method of HttpsURLConnection returns 404 in as response

Tags: android, rest, httprequest, httpurlconnection

The pin code and user name works fine in postman but whenever i call from the app it returns 404 response. And also in postman it doesnt need any header.

I have tried changing the order of the code lines but nothing seem to work.

android permission of internet is taken in manifest too.

```
    pin = "pin_code = 1111";
    uname = "username = bruce";
    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HttpsURLConnection connect = null;
            try {
                getApi = new URL("https://portal.hal.com/users/api/patient/login/with_username/");

                connect = (HttpsURLConnection) getApi.openConnection();
                connect.setDoInput (true);
                connect.setDoOutput(true);
                connect.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connect.connect();
                connect.getOutputStream().write(pin.getBytes());
                connect.getOutputStream().write(uname.getBytes());
                connect.getOutputStream().close();

                if (connect.getResponseCode() == 200 ) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"DONE");
                }  if (connect.getResponseCode() == 404){
                    Log.d(TAG,"404 error");
                }
```

Comment: your url may be wrong

Comment: I changed the url here because its confidential but the real url works fine in postman

Comment: if you use connect.setRequestMethod("POST") Don't use connect.setDoInput (true); this might override POST method to GET sometimes.Try removing both connect.setDoInput (true); and connect.setDoOutput(true);

Comment: i tried it. Doesnt work still 404 shows error

Comment: @SadidWinchester check parameters which you are giving is sent properly. debug and check.

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake. in username and password string are both sent in one string.

```
 String parameter = "pin_code=4444&username=user";
 connect.getOutputStream().write(parameter.getBytes());
```